# Load switch wiring help (UM3865-A)

Tags: pcb, switches, wiring, load

I'm making my first PCB and I was wondering if the wiring to this load switch is correct. I'm unsure, since I am not using slew-rate control, if R2 and C1 are omitted should those connections be direct or non-existent.

Thank you so much!

[image: Schematic]

[image: Datasheet example]

Answer (score 0):

Pin 1 must have a direct path to ground, so R2 should be zero ohms. With R2 as zero, R1 would then be closer to 20k but is not critical depending on desired current consumption.

C1 is removed to leave an open between pins 2,3 and pin 6.

Be careful with the word "omitted", some may interpret as an open, others as a short.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! In your opinion, is the wiring schematic that I made on the top look reasonably correct?